# How to select all unselected nodes ? d3/js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Really simple question but how do you select all unselected nodes ? I have nodes classed as .selectedNode, how do I select the inverse (everything else).

```
d3.selectAll(".selectedNode")
```

What I want to do is apply a class to all unselected nodes to hide the, : visibility:hidden

Comment: Use `d3.selectAll(":not(.selectedNode)")`.

Comment: cool, didnt know you could do it like that :) i found another way, don't know which one is better but Im guessing both work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the selector ":not" :

#### 3D JS Code :

```
d3.selectAll("div:not(.selectedNode)").style("display", "none");
```

#### Html

```
<div class="selectedNode"> <h4>Selected Node 1<h4> </div>
<div class="selectedNode"> <h4>Selected Node 2<h4> </div>
<!-- this div will be hide -->
<div class="unSelectedNode"> <h4> Unelected Node 3<h4> </div>
<div class="selectedNode"> <h4>Selected Node 4<h4> </div>
<div class="selectedNode"> <h4>Selected Node 5<h4> </div>
```

You can try it right now : http://jsfiddle.net/Bentayaa/dcavpdbr/

I hope that will help.

Best regards

Comment: selected this as the right answer even though Lars gave the same answer in the comments :) cheers man. One more question though. I have given the hidden class to my unselected nodes and I go to select some of the selected nodes, i.e narrowing down the selection ( I have a brush to select multiple nodes). But when I drag over some of the nodes, because the 'hidden' nodes are still there (just cant see them) I am able to interact with them. How can I stop all interaction with elements that are hidden ? Thanks again

Comment: @reko I haven't quite understood your question can you explain it more ?

Comment: basically, I am still able to select the nodes via the brush even though they have visibility:hidden on them. I have tried display:none but that doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @reko can you try : d3.selectAll("div:not(.selectedNode)").remove();
it will remove all unseleted nodes from DOM.

Comment: i have tried that but it doesn't apply to the SVG :/ gets rid of everything but the SVG elements :/

Answer (score 2):

Here is how  I solved it :)

```
nodes.classed("hidden", function (d)
        {
            return d.selected ? false : true;
        });
```

Basically says if its selected dont give it the hidden class but if it isnt selected give it the hidden class :)